# Rails 4 HABTM views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть 2 модели Brands и Category которые объеденные ассоциацией  has_and_belongs_to_many

models/brand.rb

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :category,  :join_table => :brand_catalogs
end
```

models/category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :brands, :join_table => :brand_catalogs
end
```

миграция

```
   class CreateBrandCatalogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :brand_catalogs, id: false do |t|
          t.belongs_to :category, index: true
          t.belongs_to :brand, index: true
        end

        add_index :brand_catalogs, [:category_id, :brand_id]

      end
    end
```

views формы brands

```
   = bootstrap_form_for [@category, @brand] do |f|
      div class='form-group'
       = f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :title)  
      = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Вопрос, как вывести связанные категории в show и index для Brand?

**Upd №1**

Добавил промежуточную модель

```
 class BrandCatalog < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :brand
 end
```

мануал https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-has-and-belongs-to-many-conveniences

**Upd №2**

по мотивам https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435937/checkbox-for-many-to-many-relationship

Модели
brand.rb

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_catalogs
  has_many :categories, through: :brand_catalogs
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_catalogs
  has_many :brands, through: :brand_catalogs
end
```

Поправил views

```
= bootstrap_form_for [:admin, @category, @brand] do |f|
  div class='form-group'
    = f.collection_check_boxes(:brand, :category_brand_ids, Category.all, :id, :title) 
  = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-success'
```

и контроллер

```
class Admin::BrandsController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :load_brand, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @brands = Brand.all
  end

  def new
    @brand = Brand.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @brand = Brand.new(brand_params)
    if @brand.save
      redirect_to admin_brands_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @brand.update(brand_params)
      redirect_to admin_brands_path
    else
       render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @brand.destroy
      redirect_to admin_brands_path
    else
    end
  end

  private
    def load_brand
      @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
    end

    def brand_params
      params.require(:brand).permit(:title, :content, :seo_title, :seo_keywords, :seo_description, :slug, :published, :logo, category_brand_ids: [])
    end
end
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать промежуточную модель `CategoryBrand`

Comment: добавил.  в show бренда вывожу `= @brand.categories`. получаю ошибку `undefined method 'categories' `. в контроллере   `def brand_params  params.require(:brand).permit(:title, :category_ids )  end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Промежуточная модель:

```
class CategoryBrand < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

Название таблицы - `category_brands`

Модель Category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_brands
  has_many :brands, through: :category_brands
end
```

Название таблицы `categories`

Модель Brand:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_brands
  has_many :categories, through: :category_brands
end
```

Название таблицы `brands`

В этом случае бренды для категории - `Category.all.first.brands`, а категории для бренда - `Brand.all.first.categories`

Comment: спасибо. за подробный ответ. а то что то совсем запутался)
все сделал но получил ошибку "uninitialized constant Brand::CategoryBrand".
в brands_controller.rb `@categories = Brand.all.first.categories`
во вюхе `div = @categories`.

Comment: @alexin Я поправил ответ. `Brand` и `Category` должны наследоваться от `ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: оно у меня так и было.

Comment: @alexin тогда перепроверь имена классов и таблиц. Должны быть в точности как в ответе.

Comment: проверил. все так. ругается "uninitialized constant Brand::CategoryBrand" на строку   в форме бренда  `= f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :title)`. в контроллере  `def brand_params
      params.require(:brand).permit(:title, category_ids: []) 
    end`

Comment: `Admin::Brands` - такого класса нету. Он ведь теперь называется `Admin::Brand`

Comment: эмм... работает все кроме формы создания бренда. проблема именно в чекбоксах. без нее все нормально работает.

модели как были так и остались. т.е .контроллеры так же должны были сохранить свои названия. т.е. модель brend.rb, таблица brends, контроллер brends_controller.rb. для namespase admin будет соотвественно app/controllers/admin/brends_controller.rb. роуты и admin_controller настроены.

Comment: проверил модели, миграции и таблицы. вроде как все так. не могу понять где именно проблема.

Comment: @alexin попробуй сделать форму руками, без хелперов. Я думаю, что проблема в хелпере `= bootstrap_form_for [:admin, @category, @brand] do |f| ...`

Comment: не помогло. убрал хелпер bootstrap
`= form_for [:admin, @category, @brand] do |f|
  div class='form-group'
    = f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :title)`

Comment: `form_for` - это тоже хелпер. Попробуй просто рукам сделать форму.

Comment: "буратино был тупой...". везде для форм хелперы используются. form_tag хотя бы. как без них то?
руками просто инпуты и пр. прописать?

Comment: Меня смущает не сам хелпер, а параметры, которые ему передаются.

Comment: т.е. проблема может в контроллере бренда?

Comment: Нет, проблема в параметрах, их количестве, формируемом URL для атрибута action, и других вещах, которые хелпер пытается сгенерировать.

Comment: тогда скорее проблема в хелпере collection_check_boxes т.к. без него работает.

Comment: ну, значит в нём

Comment: по мотивам http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/need-help-to-understand-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails
переименовал в BrandCatalog промежуточную таблицу. что бы путаницы не возникало. теперь ошибка uninitialized constant Brand::BrandCatalog